# Batching datastore ancestor-queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Let's say I have:

```
class ParentKind(db.Model):
    """These are the parents."""

class ChildKind(db.Model):
    """Children. Their parents are ParentKind objects."""
```

I then create different parent objects, `parent_1` and `parent_2`. How can I query 5 children op `parent_1` and 10 children of `parent_2` in one query? (e.g. an or-ancestor-query.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You'd have to run this as 2 queries and merge the results locally.